# How to map specific entity in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a project with multiple brandings (different subdomains) and single database. The users can login across all brandings. The users can register companies in each branding, but the company is bound to the branding (it should be inaccessible in all other brandings). I don't need a ManyToMany relation here because only the company of the current branding is important. Is here a way to make a ManyToOne relation and to map only the relevant company to the property?

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help.

```
<?php
/** @Entity **/
class Property
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Company")
     * @JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $company;
}

/** @Entity **/
class Company
{
    // ...
}
```

For further exploration: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional

Comment: it is the normal ManyToOne relation. I need something like

JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id", where="branding=branding1")